# US Boyfriend visiting me (UK citizen) for 6 weeks having just sold house

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, visas-on-arrival, removal

I previously posted this question and got some excellent advice:

[Will US boyfriend have issue visiting me in UK for 3 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/will-us-boyfriend-have-issue-visiting-me-in-uk-for-3-months)

We have changed plans to not marry in the US but instead apply for a fiance visa in the UK at a later date.

Our immediate concern is whether he will be able to enter the UK to visit me for 6 weeks, beginning in 6 days. He is self-employed as a property developer, and has recently sold his house.  He does have a return ticket to the US, and a substantial savings, so plenty of funds to support himself during his stay in the UK.

Will he be permitted to enter the UK without owning a home or more regular employment in the US?

Comment: I did edit my original question but was advised to ask a new question as just editing it made the answers (which were excellent) look incomplete..  I didn't want to make it super complicated for people so just posted the original question with my update.  Shall I delete the duplicate content in this and just leave the link?  I'm sorry to be rubbish

Comment: @Flimzy, it's a brand new question with a background of the original, but looks like the OP copied and pasted her original.  The INTENT is that the circumstances have changed and she wants to get a new take on  them.  New question, but not posed as such :(

Comment: @Hannah, that's a great edit and now looks like a fresh question. +1

Comment: It was edited for me by @flimzy I assume.  You're all so helpful! Any advice desperately and gratefully received.

Comment: Yes. Having previously taught and worked in an environment lab testing building materials he decided to move into property development and just completed his first project making him a substantial profit.  This was my first concern as he doesn't have an "employer" to write him a letter stating he must go back.  I was reassured that having a house with a mortgage in his name would be a really good tie and prove his intentions and it's just sort of dawned on me that now he just looks like a bloke visiting his girlfriend who doesn't have a house or a standard "job" to tie him to the U.S. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27098/discussion-between-hannah-and-flimzy).

Comment: @Hannah: I have further edited the question down significantly to focus just on what I believe are the relevant details after our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27098/discussion-between-hannah-and-flimzy). If you feel I was over zealous in my edit, and removed some relevant details, please feel free to add them back in again.

Comment: Congratulations by the way :)

Comment: Just wanted to say that he had no issues at the border. He was asked to show his return ticket and that was it. Indeed apparently the man on the desk seemed more impressed with the return he made on his property development than anything else and said something like "oh to be young again!" Just thought i'd update :)

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of bringing this question to an answered state...

### Summary

The OP joined a bespoke chat room and engaged with [Flimzy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/444/flimzy) (to whom thanks) for about an hour.  The OP left the chat satisfied and Flimzy was invited to provide an answer here.

The OP's friend will face a perilous landing interview: he is unemployed and without a permanent residence stateside.  These introduce the risk that he will abscond and go underground looking for work.  This risk is complicated because he has access to someone who is simultaneously  at risk of harbouring him unlawfully and helping him eventually build up a case for settlement.  On the plus side, the OP's friend appears to be well-minted and this will be taken into account.

Although the OP's friend does not need an entry clearance, he should bring all of the evidence needed to secure an entry clearance.

Performance in the landing interview is largely governed by personal impact and articulation skills.  If the OP's friend is not successful, he will be removed under [Paragraph 320 of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/422941/20150406_Immigration_Rules_-_Part_9_final_v4.pdf).