# Manchester vs Heathrow: Do they provide similar airport immigration experience to visitors?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, airports, manchester

There appears to be a lot of anecdotal evidence available online which imply that Heathrow is the worst UK international airport to enter the UK from, in terms of removals and terrible immigration experiences and that Manchester is better.

Articles like [*Heathrow’s Immigration Detention Centre is 'Among Worst' in the UK*](http://www.thetablet.co.uk/news/3084/0/heathrow-s-immigration-detention-centre-is-among-worst-in-the-uk-) and [*London Mayor: Heathrow Airport Is Giving People 'A Terrible Impression Of The UK*'](http://www.businessinsider.com/london-mayor-heathrow-airport-is-giving-people-a-terrible-impression-of-the-uk-2012-4), and [*Manchester Airport soars over Gatwick and Heathrow to be named best in UK*](http://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/business/manchester-airport-soars-over-gatwick-8469319) are among many suggesting so.

I read this `The Home Office produces statistics that inform us that approximately 1 passenger out of 2,200 arriving from the US will be removed at port` from *[Will US boyfriend have issue visiting me in UK for 3 months?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/will-us-boyfriend-have-issue-visiting-me-in-uk-for-3-months/50091#50091)* which provides data to be able to make some conclusions.

Is there data available to support the Manchester vs Heathrow assertion that someone can point me to? I am focused on the immigration experience (like removals, percent of secondary screening, time spent on landing interview etc), not the other stuff like delays, available facilities, parking, dining, etc

Comment: Any such data seems subject to confounding factors.  Even if, say, the rate of removals are different, it might simply mean that people who are actually ineligible to enter the UK are more likely to arrive at LHR than MAN - perhaps because LHR has flights from their country and MAN does not.  We would really need an "all other things equal" comparison and that would require some extremely detailed data.  In short, correlation is not causation.

Comment: @NateEldredge `correlation is not causation`- Agreed. However for such huge data sets I would expect the two populations of arriving vistiors to have enough similarity to be able to draw some general conclusion. I am not looking to build a statistical model.

Comment: I have used three UK airports--Heathrow, Gatwick and Manchester. Heathrow has the rudest officers by far. Still not a match for JFK  terminal 4 though. Those officers consider passengers "as peices of shit"

Comment: @greatone I feel your pain. Both JFK and Heathrow are airports I use quite a bit and I don't have too many good things to write about them.

Comment: This question is conflating two different things. From the point of view of these articles, "the immigration experience" is things like how long the queues are, and whether you have to walk miles in dingy corridors to get from your plane to border control, not how well it works for the tiny fraction of travellers who don't get let in after a few seconds to a minute's interaction with an IO.

Comment: Consider, the significant majority of MAN arrivals are from Schengen, EU or North American origins which presumably have a lower risk of immigration violation than arrivals at LHR.  You can make the same comparison between BOS and JFK.